# how to make/create ground truth image file for training Hyperspectral image data?

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, training-data, supervised-learning

Need to train hyperspectral data, how can I **build** a training dataset from scracth and a ground truth array/image to be used for the same? Spectral python doesn't support training by png files.

Comment: EDIT: using a .raw ENVI file with a single band is possible

Answer (score 0):

We need to manually create masks for particular classes on any 2D image and convert it into a .raw ENVI file with a single band.

Ground truth image need not be a hypercube necessarily.